# How to decrypt an AES encrypted string while having only the secret key

Tags: java, encryption

I am consuming a SOAP API that sends a response that is encrypted with AES. I too have the secret key from the API provider. However I am a bit confused on how to decrypt the response.

All guides that describe how I can decrypt the message tell me I need `SecretKeySpec` when using `javax.crypto.Cipher`. However I have no idea what is actually expected there?

Here is an example what I am trying to do:

```java
final String encryptedResponse = "F9nwhTquiEcRY3wfwCGVH1yvZ1fl28VnBXQ3vo6fyCzdV0MnOmeeHg8ea/7c/9ZT0AeEywnR06r5eUoeq4Swf/bFIixc9JJEYB7/fJ0h6I7blQbiOuks7QOUBoSMNaAum1NYTgTm0MHbM3GYLHDPlb8PkBFTL0XxZalKqcqRuhr3BQxPfITeSXjqSvPvy5Wt1Jq";
final String secretKey = "ijsdfgDJJff42h3412";

BASE64Decoder myDecoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] crypted = myDecoder.decodeBuffer(secretKey);
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
byte[] cipherData = cipher.doFinal(crypted);
String decryptedResponse = new String(cipherData);
```

here I receive the following error

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher
```

Comment: the key isn't the correct size, you're trying to decrypt the key instead of the data, the data looks base64 encoded, your cipher instance relies on default values... most lines of code here have a problem. There's no point in trying to decrypt something if you don't know how it was encrypted. By how I don't mean "with AES" but full details about the the mode, the keys, the data, and how everything is encoded.

Answer (score -1):

The key length should be 16,get the true key first;

mayby the key length should be 16,get the true key first;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).